# polars python: split string in lazyframe column into new columns

Tags: python, python-polars

I could not find any helpful info on that so if anyone has some input.... please....

I need to split all string in a column in a big (ca 30 GB) csv file. For that I tried out polars. Seems to work fine but I dont understand how I can map the values from the list I get after splitting the string into separate columns with lazyframes. Any input?

What I have:

```
import polars as pl

# Create a LazyFrame 
lf = pl.LazyFrame({"sample": ["ENST123456768.19", "ENST987654321.20", "ENST567890123.21"], "banananana": ["chiqita", "baaan", "banabana"]})
# Define a function to split the "sample" column and create new columns

lf = lf.with_columns(pl.struct(pl.col('sample').str.split('.'))).unnest('sample')

lf.sink_parquet('test.parquet')

test_Df = pl.read_parquet('test.parquet')
print(test_Df.head())
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ sample                  ┆ banananana │
│ ---                     ┆ ---        │
│ list[str]               ┆ str        │
╞═════════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ ["ENST123456768", "19"] ┆ chiqita    │
│ ["ENST987654321", "20"] ┆ baaan      │
│ ["ENST567890123", "21"] ┆ banabana   │
└─────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

What I try to do:
the column "sample" should become 2 columns:

```
┌────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ sample             ┆  version   ┆ banananana │
│ ---                ┆  ---       ┆ ---        │
│ str                ┆  str       ┆ str        │
╞════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ ENST123456768      ┆ 19         │ chiqita    │
│ ENST987654321      ┆ 20         │ baaan      │
│ ENST567890123      ┆ 21         │ banabana   │
└────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

I thought how hard can it be to achieve with lazyframes. Yeah I already wasted more than 8 hours... So, its pretty complicated I guess?
Any help is highly apreciated!
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using `str.split_exact` and then `unnest`:

```py
import polars as pl

lf = pl.LazyFrame({"sample": ["ENST123456768.19", "ENST987654321.20", "ENST567890123.21"], "banananana": ["chiqita", "baaan", "banabana"]})

lf = lf.with_columns(pl.col('sample').str.split_exact('.', 1)).unnest("sample")
lf.sink_parquet('test.parquet')

test_Df = pl.read_parquet('test.parquet')
print(test_Df.head())
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ field_0       ┆ field_1 ┆ banananana │
│ ---           ┆ ---     ┆ ---        │
│ str           ┆ str     ┆ str        │
╞═══════════════╪═════════╪════════════╡
│ ENST123456768 ┆ 19      ┆ chiqita    │
│ ENST987654321 ┆ 20      ┆ baaan      │
│ ENST567890123 ┆ 21      ┆ banabana   │
└───────────────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

You can then easily rename the columns if you need

### Edit:

As suggested in the comments here is the code to rename the columns and cast the `version` column to uint:

```py
...

lf.with_columns(pl.col('sample').str.split_exact('.', 1)).unnest("sample").rename({'field_0':'sample', 'field_1': 'version'})  # rename the columns
lf = lf.with_columns(pl.col('version').cast(pl.UInt8))  # cast version to uint
lf.sink_parquet('test.parquet')

...
```

Comment: thank you very much!! MVP of the day :D If you could update with these two lines `lf = lf.with_columns(pl.col('sample').str.split_exact('.', 1)).unnest("sample").rename({'field_0':'sample', 'field_1': 'version'})` (basically just adding the rename) and `lf = lf.with_columns(pl.col('version').cast(pl.UInt8))`, to rename the columns and cast the dtype, I think that could be very helpful for others. Anyways thanks again for your answer!!!

Comment: @awesome_crab I have added this information to my answer